# How to get position of button in GridView where to place it using tag?

Tags: java, android

I want to know position, where the button located in GridView using tag, and after getting the position, get letter from that button using position. 
Here is the code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) 
    {  
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.buttonlist, null);
    } 

    final Button btn= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.letterbtn);
    btn.setText(word[position]+"");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            btn.setTag(btn);
            String tag=btn.getTag().toString();

            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });

    return v; 
}
```

Comment: Have you done with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 final Button btn= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.letterbtn);
  // btn.setText(word[position]+"");
     btn.setTag(position);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
         // btn.setTag(btn);
         String pos=btn.getTag().toString();
         //You get a position of that button
         Log.e("position",pos); 
         //You get a word of that position
         Log.e("word",""+word[Integer.parseInt(pos)]); 

         btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

});
```